# Php sockets, Apache and CentOS 6.3 gives Permission denied

Tags: php, apache, sockets, centos, minecraft

What I am trying to do is running a simple PHP script that checks if a game server is online and gets some info from it. I am running exactly this same script on a local box with WAMP Server where i just uncommented php_openssl.dll and php_sockets.dll and - voila - it was working as expected.

But then came our production environment! I usually work with Debian, but our host decided to install CentOS on our dedicated server because the NIC was failing in Debian, and it's been nothing but trouble since.

I overcame a few issues, and am left with this problem: how do I fix PHP sockets? I read that I needed php-common, so I installed this with:

```
# yum install php-common
```

Then i checked `phpinfo()` and I got this

```
'./configure'  '--with-openssl' '--enable-sockets' ...
```

So this is looking good if you ask me, both openssl and sockets are installed and should be working, however this is not the case. I found this script here on Stack Overflow:

```
<?php
//just in case
if (!extension_loaded('sockets')) {
die('The sockets extension is not loaded.');
}
echo '<p><strong>Establishing connection...</strong></p>';
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if (!socket_connect($socket, "stackoverflow.com", 80))
{
die('Socket error : '.socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
}

echo '<p><strong>Connection successful!</strong></p>';

$request = join("\n",array(
"GET / HTTP/1.1",
"Connection: close",
"Host: stackoverflow.com",
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)",
"Accept: text/html,*/*;q=0.8",
""));
socket_write($socket,$request,strlen($request));

$response = socket_read($socket,2048);


echo "<p><strong>This is the received data : </strong></p>";
echo '<pre>'.htmlentities($response).'</pre>';

socket_close($socket);
```

What this outputs surprises me completely:

```
Establishing connection...

Connection successful!

This is the received data :

HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>
Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.
</body></html>
```

But still, my script is not functioning ? :(
I have disabled iptables with

```
# service iptables stop
```

just to be sure it's not a firewall issue. What happens is the following, when I open the page instead of a game servers name I get this:

> Warning: socket_connect(): unable to connect [13]: Permission denied in /var/www/test.php on line 9 <<<

This is the code I'm using, it's open source from xPaw, so I take no credit for it:

```
<?php
function queryserver( $IP, $Port = 25565, $Timeout = 2 )
{
$Socket = Socket_Create( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP );
Socket_Set_Option( $Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array( 'sec' => (int)$Timeout, 'usec' => 0 ) );
Socket_Set_Option( $Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array( 'sec' => (int)$Timeout, 'usec' => 0 ) );
if( $Socket === FALSE || Socket_Connect( $Socket, $IP, (int)$Port ) === FALSE )
{
return FALSE;
}
Socket_Send( $Socket, "\xFE\x01", 2, 0 );
$Len = @Socket_Recv( $Socket, $Data, 256, 0 );
Socket_Close( $Socket );
if( $Len < 4 || $Data[ 0 ] !== "\xFF" )
{
return FALSE;
}
$Data = SubStr( $Data, 3 );
$Data = iconv( 'UTF-16BE', 'UTF-8', $Data );

if( $Data[ 1 ] === "\xA7" && $Data[ 2 ] === "\x31" )
{
$Data = Explode( "\x00", $Data );
return Array(
'HostName'   => $Data[ 3 ],
'Players'    => IntVal( $Data[ 4 ] ),
'MaxPlayers' => IntVal( $Data[ 5 ] ),
'Protocol'   => IntVal( $Data[ 1 ] ),
'Version'    => $Data[ 2 ]
);
}
$Data = Explode( "\xA7", $Data );
return Array(
'HostName'   => SubStr( $Data[ 0 ], 0, -1 ),
'Players'    => isset( $Data[ 1 ] ) ? IntVal( $Data[ 1 ] ) : 0,
'MaxPlayers' => isset( $Data[ 2 ] ) ? IntVal( $Data[ 2 ] ) : 0,
'Protocol'   => 0,
'Version'    => '1.3'
);
}

$test = queryserver('SERVERADDRESSHERE'); // (i tried multiple, which are all working @wamp)
$echo = $test['HostName'] . "<<< <br />";
echo $echo;
```

Comment: Why use sockets for this?

Answer (score 25):

Try this command in your linuxbox (as root).

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Comment: Save my day!   Thx

Comment: WOW you save my day

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, so I figured I would drop an answer here also for the next person that runs into this. A way of going about it, without disabling/limiting SELinux, is to change the policy surrounding your httpd.

Hope this saves 2 days for the next person reading this. lol

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/html
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

I found the answer. Seems SELinux is blocking the socket connections. Disabled SE Linux with '# setenforce Permissive' and it works now. Just in case anybody is experiencing the same strangeness.